# Can't install RPM on Centos 6

Tags: centos, kernel, rpm, centos6

please explain me this :

I'll try to upgrade kernel from RPM and I have got the next dependency :

```
rpm -i ./dracut-kernel-004-388.el6.noarch.rpm

error: Failed dependencies:
        dracut = 004-388.el6 is needed by dracut-kernel-004-388.el6.noarch
```

Can somebody explain me how I can install this rpm? Thx

Answer (score 1):

There is package dracut-kernel, which requires package dracut.

You should not call rpm directly, rather use abstraction layer above, which resolve the deps for you:

```
yum install dracut-kernel
```

or

```
dnf install dracut-kernel
```